# Having multiple select boxes open the same modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a form that allows the user to add users to a contact list. I have multiple select boxes that allow the user to select a user to add, but I also want the user to be able to add someone that is not in the list. So, when new user is selected, I want a modal dialog to pop up with a form to create a user. This same form should show up regardless of which box is being used. As such, I gave them all the same class name, and I am using the following code to detect the new user option.

```
$(function()
{
    $( ".select-user" ).change(function()
    {
        alert("List Changed");
            if ($(this).val() == 'new')
            {
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                updateTips("* indicates a mandatory field.");
            }
    });
});
```

However, only the first box is triggering this event. The first select is defined as such:

```
<select id ="select-user" class = "select-user" name="foo">
```

The other boxes are all the same, and they start hidden.

```
<select style="visibility:hidden" class="select-user" id="select-user-$index" name="bar">
```

And they are being made visible by the following code:

```
document.getElementById('select-user-$index').style.visibility = "visible";
```

I have confirmed that the .change event is not triggering at all for anything but the first select. Is there something I'm missing about how the event is triggered?

EDIT:
As I said in isherwood's answer, isolating the select box's code in jsfiddle provides the expected behavior. So, some more information about the page.
Both selects are being generated by (almost) the same php. I copied and pasted it for the most part, but just added lines to hide the additional boxes and changed the ids.

Both selects are in the same form. The first one is inside of a table, whereas the additional ones are being thrown into a .

Every select box after the first two is being added via javascript.

Comment: The alert is there in the event for debugging purposes.

Comment: You're sure that the other selects are already in DOM before document is ready and `$(function(){})` triggered?

Comment: They're all being generated by the same php file. So, they should be.

Comment: You forgot a quote mark in your last line of code..

Comment: Typo. I'm actually using a variable for it in my actual js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tLYDB/2/

```
$(function () {
    $(".select-user").each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            alert("List Changed");

            if ($(this).val() == 'new') {
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
                updateTips("* indicates a mandatory field.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try the demo? Works beautifully. If you disagree, be more specific about what's not working.

Comment: The demo works fine, but if I replace my code with that one, the behavior hasn't changed at all.

Comment: To add to that: placing two of my selects in the demo works. The problem has to be coming from somewhere else. I'll place more info in the first post.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Start with a snippet of rendered HTML.

Comment: Alright, looks like the issue was related to the extra select boxes being hidden. Just need to fun the change code again and it works fine.

Comment: These are not the droids you're looking for. This is the answer you're looking for. You will click its checkmark as payment for the assistance you've received.